# Comparison of alphanumeric data in two columns, Excel VBA

Tags: algorithm, comparison, alphanumeric

I got a simple sheet in which I got some columns of data representing certain grid-line i.e. A-25, B-35, C-41 etc and I got another column in which the data is like B-25.5, C-26.5 etc. I want to compare the both columns and know for each item that which item is bigger or smaller (grid-line sense) than the other. e.g. C-26.5 will surely be lesser than C-41. I need a simple algorithm or code to achieve the same.

Comment: It's not clear to me how "C-26.5 will surely be lesser than C-41". I thought initially that C-25 represented "col C, row 25" but that doesn't seem to be the case, can you clarify your notation?

Comment: Hi Mathias. C-26.5 and all other such notations actually represent the data as on actual grid-line (like grid paper). So you have sometimes C-26 (26 being whole number) and sometimes C-26.5 where 26.5 is fractional number now.

Comment: Anyone who can respond ! Second time that my query is going unanswered :(

Comment: Well guys I've really worked out the solution and will soon be posting the same for everybody's reference. This time I really had to push myself to get the solution. Still thanks.